# What is the meaning of "削平巨寇"?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I read the sentence 岳飞真是一员猛将，在很短的几天内削平巨寇。

削 means cut

巨 means huge

how to read the 削平巨寇？ it means cut the 巨寇？

Comment: Where did you get “巨 means cut”?

Comment: @dROOOze sorry i edit it

Comment: 削 should be pronounced as xuē here.

Comment: The meaning of 削平 here is closer to "defeat" rather than its literal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

岳飞真是一员猛将，
Yue fei really was a fearsome general,
在很短的几天内削平巨寇。
in just a few days he crushed a huge enemy force.

削平: flatten, raze to the ground, reduce, crush
巨寇: big foe

Comment: I put what you said to my chinese friends and they say what you said have no imposing manner.

Comment: @daotian -- Just for my general education, what does "... have no imposing manner" means in the context of Pedroski's answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to dictionaries, 削平(as a verb) means:

> 平定(put down)

> E.g. 削平乱贼

巨寇 is obvious and literal(大的敌寇). 巨: huge;big; 寇: bandit;invader;enemy

Comment: Maybe invader is better than bandit here? Yue Fei fought against the army of Jin all his life, not a group of robbers.

Comment: And 倭寇 can only refer to Japanese invaders!

Comment: @T-Pioneer ok, just edit

Comment: @T-Pioneer 倭寇 was 日本浪人(流氓) came from sea to rob the local Chinese, and retreated after emptied the local, it was similar to the Chinese 山寇(土匪) who terrorized and robbed the local for living, the only difference was where they were based, both are far away from the more strict definition of invader (入侵者), who invade and occupy/grab territory.

Comment: @r13 Maybe you are right. But during World War II 倭寇 referred to the Japanese Army too.  Maybe a better definition is "**the Japanese pirates who plundered China and Korea in the 14th~16th Centuries. Or Japanese Army who invaded China in WWII**"?

Comment: @T-Pioneer The Chinese calling Japanese army 日寇 was looking down on them because their horrific actions against the people in the occupied land were similar to 土匪. Can you cite another foreign invader been called 寇? I can remember more often they were called "狗", such as 金狗, 元狗, 清狗.

Comment: See this article: 《红衣大炮：清军驱逐俄寇的秘密武器》https://www.163.com/dy/article/G02G3A290543OQDA.html